# Merge changes to all child branches in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

I have base branch, 3 child branches and each of those have 3 branches for a total of 12 child branches from the base.

I just made a change to the base branch that I would like merged into all 12 child branches.  Is it possible to merged the changes to all child brances at once?  Or must I merge them all individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could perform the merge operation on the changeset three times from `base` to the child branches. But you would then need to baseless merge the changes from `base` to grandchild branches also.

I have no idea what would happen if you tried to merge the changeset with a check-in into 12 branches though.

Personally, I'd just bite the bullet and merge it to each branch down the hierarchy. This has the benefit of making it easy to track the individual changes, deal with conflicts and doesn't require any baseless merges.

Comment: I will look into doing baseless merges as an option for streamlining the process in the future.  Sounds like there could be some danger there though.  I ended up just merging them all down the hierarchy.  Really only took 5 minutes, I just wondered if there was a more efficient way.

Comment: You definitely should not use baseless merges for that, deletes and renames may not be merged properly this way, further more it may cause issues during future merges.

Answer (score 0):

faced a similar situation earlier with this. One simple solution I took was to write a small shell script that automated the process a little. Below is a sample:

```
@echo Merge - Product ABC
@"%VS100COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\tf.exe" merge /recursive "Base\CORE" "$/.../tfs/path/to/ABC"

@echo Merge - Product XYZ
@"%VS100COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\tf.exe" merge /recursive "Base\CORE" "$/.../tfs/path/to/XYZ"

@echo Merge - Product 123
@"%VS100COMNTOOLS%..\IDE\tf.exe" merge /recursive "Base\CORE" "$/.../tfs/path/to/123"
```

There are obvious flaws with this approach, but if you find yourself merging the same shared base to many child branches this can at least speed the process up.

Once the script is executed you can simply check everything in (in bulk if all under the same roof).

Also as a side note, if you copy the script and swap the src and dst paths then that can essentially backwards integrate all changes made in child branches back to the main base ;)